# How to project data onto a model (specifically, GMM)?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, projection

I'm using data to train a Gaussian mixture model (GMM). I then take a sample and would like to see its projection on the GMM 'space'. I can think of an optimization problem such as this: consider $y$ to be my sample and $p(x)$ my trained GMM. $ll(x)=log(p(x))$ is the log-likelihood function. Therefore, $\hat{y}$ shall be the projection, defined as:

$$
\hat{y}=\arg\min_u ||u-y||_2^2-ll(u),
$$
which makes sense as it seeks the closest $u$ to $y$ but keeping the log-likelihood of $u$ high enough.

Does this make sense? are there any standard ways to do that specifically in the case of GMM (I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "projecting data onto a model"? If you are also not sure, then maybe the following question will help. What do you plan to do after you get this "projection"?

Comment: I have a model for how the data should behave (alternatively, describes the manifold on which it resides), and I have a sample that's out of the manifold and I would like to find the best approximation of the sample constrained to be on the manifold. This manifold is described as all possible samples spanned by the GMM model.

Comment: The way I'm looking at it is that if my manifold was all points of the form $(x,0)$ and my points was $(x_0,y_0)$, then the result would be $(x_0,0)$. Here the manifold structure is much more complicated...

Comment: I can imagine what you said if you had a surface, a point outside it, and you want to project it down to the surface. But how do you see a Gaussian mixture model as a surface? Do you, say, take a quantile to form the surface boundary..?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then what you are looking for is a way to make `predictions' with a mixture model, that is, to find out what is the mean of an observation according to the model.

Let's start with the obvious case of a one component mixture. That is:
$$
y_1,...,y_n \sim N(\mu, \Sigma).
$$ 
We can estimate $\mu$ with the sample mean $\hat\mu = \bar{y}$ and then the prediction for any unobserved value is simply $\hat\mu$.

Things are a bit more complicated for mixture models. Assume the following model:
$$
y_1,...,y_n \sim \sum_{k=1}^{K}\pi_k N(\mu_k, \Sigma), \qquad \sum_{k=1}^{K}\pi_k = 1.
$$
Given estimates for the parameters, the expected value for any new observation is :
$$
E(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{K}\hat\pi_k \hat\mu_k.
$$

Now this solution is obviously unsatisfactory as what we are looking for is a way to estimate the expected value of an observation $y_i$ based on the model and the observed information. For this purpose, let us pose this problem as a Bayesian one. Suppose that $E(y_i) = \nu_i$ where:
$$
\nu_i \sim \sum_{k}\pi_k \delta_0(\mu_k),
$$
that is, the prior for $\nu_i$ is discrete with probabilities at the estimated mean values. Now,
$$
E(\nu_i | y_i) = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \hat\mu_{k} P(\nu_i = \hat\mu_k | y_i)
$$
where,
$$
P(\nu_i = \hat\mu_k|y_i) = \frac{\varphi(y_i ; \hat\mu_k, \Sigma)\hat\pi_k}{\sum_{l=1}^{K}\varphi(y_i;\hat\mu_l,\Sigma)\hat\pi_l}.
$$
That is, the best estimate for the expected value of $y_i$ given $y_i$ is the posterior mean of $\nu_i$.